# Changes to parameter not showing on Report Server after deployment

Tags: visual-studio-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have 7 parameters (3 multi select of string, 1 DateTime, 3 string values) in my SSRS 2008 report, and I have set all the parameters as null in the *default value*.

It's working fine in my preview window of Visual Studio 2008. But **after deployment** to my report server, **the "NULL" checkbox for the parameter is not checked**, causing the report not to get loaded at initially.

Comment: instead of define the params as null, have you tried to define their values as `""` ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is "by design":

When you first [deploy reports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159615.aspx), parameters are uploaded with all their settings.

Administrators of those reports are then allowed to tweak the way report parameters function in the [report web manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157147.aspx): change whether they accept null values, defaults, etc.

If you *redeploy* reports later, *nothing is changed to existing parameters* (the system doesn't want to "overwerite" changes made by report admins).

**Solutions:**

- Delete the report, *then* redeploy it.
- Change the parameter settings directly in the deployed report.