# How to set hidden parameter in a subscription

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

We have an SSRS 2008 (not R2) report, which returns data for 2 different customer class types in a single datatable.

I have a request to have this report sent via email automatically to the user as an excel attachment.  The user would like to have 2 worksheets in the spreadsheet.  The first worksheet should have the result set including both customer class types and the second worksheet should only contain the result set for one of the 2 class types.
I am able to accomplish getting the 2 worksheets exported to excel, by adding a second data table to the report and setting the pagebreak property on the second table to start and to then set a filter on the second datatable, to only include the 1 class type the user wants.
I can then set up a subscription to automate this on schedule.

The issue that I have, is that I don't want 2 datatables to display when the user is executing the report on-demand via the SSRS web page.  To accomplish this, I created a hidden boolean parameter which I use (in the expression) to set the value of the hidden property of the second datatable.  This will allow me to hide the second datatable by default. I am expecting to be able to set the value to not hide when setting the parameters for the subscription. However, I can't seem to figure out how to set the value of this parameter in the Subscription.  The parameters displayed in the subscription are the ones which are not hidden.  This hidden parameter is not displayed in the subscription.

Is there a way to set the parameter values of either a hidden or internal parameter in a subscribtion?  Optionally, if I can detect at runtime that the report is being executed by the subscription, then I can set the parameter value accordingly.????

Comment: I actually figured this out.

As per this posting [http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/337c7ae9-f15a-4718-9fac-e5c1d6a73f30/][1].  I deleted the report and uploaded it again, and it works.

Apparently, when you deploy a report more then once, the parameter settings do not override. Only the report overrrides with a new definition.


  [1]: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/337c7ae9-f15a-4718-9fac-e5c1d6a73f30/

Comment: Good to hear you found the problem. See my answer to the duplicate question "[Changes to parameter not showing on Report Server after deployment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14701233/changes-to-parameter-not-showing-on-report-server-after-deployment)" for some info on this behavior.