# Clickthrough links not working in snapshot of linked report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a linked report, which is running fine. It is cached, there is a cache refresh-plan, that all works fine. But I would like to use it as a snapshot. So I enabled 'Render this report from a report snapshot' with a schedule. Now when I run this linked snapshotted report it complains that it cannot find the clickthrough reports.

This is not problem in the (pre)cached linked version of the same report. Anything else is identical (location, params and such), only difference is the setting 'Render this report from a report snapshot' instead of 'Render this report from a report snapshot'.

Structure:

```
\DATASETS
\DATA Sources
\MAINREPORTS\MainReport.rdl  
\MAINREPORTS\SubReport1.rdl  
\MAINREPORTS\SubReport2.rdl  
\PUBLIC\Dashboard.rdl  (linked to \MAINREPORTS\MainReport.rdl )
```

So when running `\PUBLIC\Dashboard.rdl` as a cached report it runs fine, when running it as a snapshot it fails; it complains it cannot find `\PUBLIC\SubReportX.rdl`

Is this known behaviour? Can I snapshot a linked report with links to reports in a different folder?

Thanks for thinking with me!

Comment: What is your setting for the subreports? Live or cached...? Also, which reports have parameters, what are their defaults, and did you make sure the [parameters changed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14701233/changes-to-parameter-not-showing-on-report-server-after-deployment) when deploying?

Comment: @Jeroen I will collect that info. All parameters are integers either filled with the result of a query set or set manually, but all have valid default values, there are no NULLS, EMPTY or strings. Whether the targeted reports  are cached or not, does not make a difference. All of the reports run with defaults params set. There are no internal params, some are made invisible though. All reports have parameters, I have been very carefull in making sure that when a report is called all params have been set, either by default or by the execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this by creating linked reports for the missing subreports in the same location as the mainreport;

\DATASETS
\DATA Sources
\MAINREPORTS\MainReport.rdl
\MAINREPORTS\SubReport1.rdl
\MAINREPORTS\SubReport2.rdl
\PUBLIC\Dashboard.rdl   (linked to \MAINREPORTS\MainReport.rdl )
\PUBLIC\SubReport1.rdl  (linked to \MAINREPORTS\SubReport1.rdl )
\PUBLIC\SubReport2.rdl  (linked to \MAINREPORTS\SubReport2.rdl )

I adapted the reportviewercontrol so when building the menutree it ignores all reports whose name starts with sub*. This way the user is not confused by all these reports showing up.

This works. It seems the subreports are not snapshotted but they are pretty small so this is not an issue. I still do not understand why this problem occurs when a reported is snapshotted and not when its cached...... If anyone does, feel free to explain that to me. For now, when snapshotting linked reports that has click-throughs to other reports, I will create links to those other reports too.