# SSRS Report Parameter Value is not getting

Tags: c#, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, parameter-passing, xmldatasource

I have one SSRS report which is using XML Data source by using web service.

In my  web service i am using one parameter to query the records. While i publish and run the service directly from iis, its getting the parameter value and returns the correct data.

For using in my projects i had converted this web service to share point web service and placesd in ISAPI folder. But when i try to run the report, first loading of report is going as fine, but when i select one parameter from the drop down, it always returns null to web service, i am not getting the selected parameter value in web service file.

Please help me to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance

Comment: Perhaps you're experiencing [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14703288/419956)?

Comment: Oh wait, on second thought, that just links to another question by you, sorry. (leaving my comment though, it may help others that land on this question)