# Dataset doesn't refresh data in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

here is my problem. I had had defalut values in the parameter and displaying of the report - both locally and on webpage went great. Then I wanted to cancel default values and this time only locally I didn't have this value. On the web page the report still displayed content with default parameter values. Why is that? Any ideas? The things I ve done: delete cookies, clean browser cache, I've deleted .data files, I've matched 'always refresh' option in report parameter properties. I would be grateful for support.
Artur

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14701233/changes-to-parameter-not-showing-on-report-server-after-deployment/

Comment: Yup sounds like the same issue. Parameter settings such as defaults are not updated when the report is redeployed. You can delete the existing report from the "web page" (assuming you mean Report Manager) and redeploy it for the new settings to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the report completely from Report Manager and re-deploy it, or go into report manager and update the parameters from there. Parameters have been an issue when deploying reports since the dawn of time and I believe it's on purpose actually.