# "Allow Null Value" not working in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a parameter in my SSRS report which I have marked as "Allow Null Value". But when I dont send that parameter from my C# code. I get the below error.

*Message=This report requires a default or user-defined value for the report parameter 'UserID'. To run or subscribe to this report, you must provide a parameter value. (rsReportParameterValueNotSet)*

Here is the parameter configuration. Available Values and Default Values tabs are marked as "None".

In some conditions, I don't want to send that parameter. But it wont allow. What else am I missing?

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you are experiencing [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14701233/419956)?

Comment: That was it.. Thanks Jeroen !!! So sad I can't mark your answer as accepted !!!

Comment: That's ok, glad I could help. Let's mark your Q as a duplicate so others with your symptoms will quickly spot the solution.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a NULL or don't want to pass a value, then include this in the URL:

```
&UserID:IsNull=True
```

Comment: which URL is this? In my C# code, I use the ReportViewer.ServerReport.Render() method to send the parameters and get a byte stream..