# Have parameter default to null

Tags: reporting-services

My SSRS report has a dataset using this query

```
select c1, c2 
from t1 
where c3 = isnull(@parameter1, c3)
```

In the report, I set the parameter (@parameter1) to 'Allow null value' and default value to null. The parameter will from another data set.

I want the report to run automatically with the default null value parameter. But now the report is still waiting for the parameter to be selected to run. Why? Or how to achieve what I want?

P.S

Also please find attached screen shots for the parameter and the query. This is not exactly the same as in the description because I was just trying to demonstrate the issue. But you get the idea.

[image]

[image]

The query:

```
    select
    t.a, 
    t.b

    from
    (
    select 1 as a, 2 as b
    union all

    select 3 as a, 4 as b
    ) as t
    where t.a =isnull( @p, t.a)
```

Comment: Perhaps you are experiencing [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14701233/419956)?

Comment: A screenshot of how you are setting the default value to NULL would be helpful.

Comment: @Jeroen I am working in BIDS, not in the stage of deploying to report server.

Comment: @BryanEargle Screen shots added.

Comment: Looks like you've got it right, I'm unable to reproduce in BIDS 10.50.4297.0 with the parameter options and dataset you specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query for the Available Values of your parameter needs to have a `Null` option for the default value of `Null` to be selected.

So your query that populates the parameter needs to something like

```
SELECT A, B
FROM MyTable
UNION ALL
SELECT Null AS A, '<All Values>' AS B
ORDER BY 2
```

where A is the Value and B is the Label.

Answer (score 0):

If Visual Studio shows default parameters well but SSRS site does not - DELETE the SSRS site report & deploy